# Typescript error on rendered component when using react-redux connect function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a component class that I am using react-redux to connect the redux store to, but I am getting an error when I try to pass the component into the connect function.

```
class FileItem extends Component<IFileItemProps, undefined> {
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IFileItemReduxState): IFileItemReduxProps => {
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): IFileItemDispatchProps => {
};

// This FileItem component passed into the below parameter is where I am getting the error

export default connect<IFileItemReduxProps, IFileItemDispatchProps, IFilePassedProps, IFileItemReduxState>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FileItem);
```

These are each of the interfaces that I am using (except for Dispatch being from redux):

```
export interface IFileItemProps {
    file: FileDirectoryNode;
    fileExplorerInfo: FileExplorerReducerState;
    selectFile: (file: FileDirectoryNode) => void;
    openFile: (file: FileDirectoryNode) => void;
}

export interface IFilePassedProps {
    file: FileDirectoryNode;
}

export interface IFileItemReduxState {
    fileExplorer: FileDirectoryTree;
}

export interface IFileItemReduxProps {
    fileExplorerInfo: FileDirectoryTree;
}

export interface IFileItemDispatchProps {
    selectFile: (file: FileDirectoryNode) => void;
    openFile: (file: FileDirectoryNode) => void;
}
```

**IFileItemProps:** All the types that the component will utilize

**IFilePassedProps:** These are the props passed into the component from the parent, 
so I dont see typing issues on the rendered component element.

**IFileItemReduxState:** The state passed to mapStateToProps from react-redux.

**IFileItemReduxProps**:  The props returned from mapStateToProps from react-redux.

**IFileItemDispatchProps**:  The props that are returned from mapDispatchToProps from react-redux.

From what I understand the connect function is typed like so:

```
connect<TReturnedMapStateToProps = {}, TReturnedMapDispatchToProps = {}, TPassedFromOutsideProps= {}, TReduxState = {}>
```

But when I do that, I am getting the following error like so:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, I found that the type of the property 'fileExplorerInfo' is different in your IFileItemProps and IFileItemReduxProps interfaces.

Did you mean the type to say FileDirectoryTree or FileExplorerReducerState?

That being said, I ran into a similar issue where my component's signature was not matching. Luckily for me I had no pass-through props so I fixed it like this

```
class FileItem extends Component<IFileItemProps &
                                 IFileItemReduxProps & 
                                 IFileItemDispatchProps, undefined> {}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IFileItemReduxState): IFileItemReduxProps =>{};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): IFileItemDispatchProps => {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FileItem);
```

Hope this helps :)